# How to save my app background in SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a fragment with a button that sets a background theme for the whole app. I have set up an interface so the fragment can tell the main activity to set the background or remove it depending on what button the user clicks.

**The problem is that every time the app is opened the background isn't saved and needs to be toggled again. I have seen that this can be solved with SharedPreferences but implementing it here is confusing me**

**In my fragment** This presents two buttons that send the values 1 or 2 to the main activity to toggle the background

```
enable = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.enable);
enable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.themechanged(2);
            enable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            disable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
    disable = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.disable);
    disable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.themechanged(1);
            disable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            enable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

**In my Main Activity** This takes the value from the listener and toggles the background depending on what the value is

```
    @Override

    public void themechanged(int value) {

    if(value==2) {
        if (isDarkTheme) {
            appbackground.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            shade.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            appbackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            shade.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }else if(value!=2||value==1){
            appbackground.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            shade.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SharedPrefence` to store the value for theme like-:

**Global Variable**

```
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

In **OnCreateView()**

```
pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Theme", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = pref.edit();
```

Now, store `preferences` on **`Button`** click

```
enable = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.enable);
enable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

      editor.putInt("yourTheme", 2);
      editor.commit();
        listener.themechanged(2);
        enable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        disable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
});
disable = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.disable);
disable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editor.putInt("yourTheme", 1);
        editor.commit();
        listener.themechanged(1);
        disable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        enable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

and then, In **OnCreate()** of **MainActivity** you can check like

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Theme", MODE_PRIVATE);
value= pref.getInt("yourTheme", 1);//1 is default value

if(value==2) {
    if (isDarkTheme) {
        appbackground.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        shade.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        appbackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        shade.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}else if(value==1){
        appbackground.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        shade.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Done, it may be helpful

Comment: would it need to be SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Theme", MODE_PRIVATE);
since it's in a fragment?

Comment: Getting a null pointer exception for some reason, checking my code

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at (HomeFragment.java:94)

line 94 is SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Theme", MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: @Alpoe change MODE_PRIVATE to Context.MODE_PRIVATE as mentioned in edited code

Comment: no change. still null pointer exception in the same place. For some reason it works when it's declared in onClick, but then the app doesnt remember when you disable the background.

Comment: I think your getActivity() is returning null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156478/discussion-between-ultimatedevil-and-alpoe).

Comment: Cheers man, it worked. I was actually just trying what you updated but I didn't do it for the editor as well so crashed. Working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

In the `onClick()` you should do 2 things:

- Sent the value to the listener (you're already doing this)
- Save this value to the preferences (already posted how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values))

Then, in the `onCreate()` of your `MainActivity` you should check for that preference and do the same you are doing on `themechanged(int)`

Actually, you could use only one `onClickListener()`, this way:

```
// Not need to cast to `Button`, since all views can have an onClickListener
rootView.findViewById(R.id.enable).setOnClickListener(clickListener)
rootView.findViewById(R.id.enable).setOnClickListener(clickListener)

// Put this as a member of your Fragment class.
View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.enable) {
            // Save your preference here
            // ... 
            listener.themechanged(2);
            enable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            disable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);            
        }

        if (v.getId() == R.id.R.id.disable) {
            // Save your preference here
            // ... 
            listener.themechanged(2);
            disable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            enable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me share this more complex example which can cover this and future needs: https://gist.github.com/walterpalladino/4f5509cbc8fc3ecf1497f05e37675111
The PersistenceManager class is generic, all your app data should be included in the Settings class.
I hope it helps.