# How to save background with sharedPreferences

Tags: android, background, sharedpreferences, spinner, background-color

hello friends I change the background with a spinner but I can't save the background with shared preferences can you help me?   But if I delete the .setBackgroundColor() in position, the instant background won't change, I really don't understand.
the code is all. I cannot save the color code for this SharedPrence. By the way, I'm new to ANDROID.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
 ConstraintLayout tasarım;
 private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

private Spinner spinner;
private ArrayList<String> renkler = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> veriAdaptoru;
String color;


    tasarım=(ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.tasarım);
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    renkler.add("beyaz");
    renkler.add("mavi");
    renkler.add("kırmızı");
    renkler.add("yeşil");
    veriAdaptoru = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, renkler);
    spinner.setAdapter(veriAdaptoru);

    sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.sondev", MODE_PRIVATE);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences("color",MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();

            String colorSec="";

            if (position==0){
                tasarım.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                colorSec="WHITE";
                editor.putString("colour",colorSec);
                editor.commit();
            }
            else if (position==1){
                tasarım.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                colorSec="BLUE";
                editor.putString("colour",colorSec);
                editor.commit();
            }
            else if(position==2){
                tasarım.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                colorSec="RED";
                editor.putString("colour",colorSec);
                editor.commit();
            }else if (position==3){
                colorSec="GREEN";
                editor.putString("colour",colorSec);
                editor.commit();
                tasarım.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            else {
                colorSec="GREEN";
                editor.putString("colour",colorSec);
                editor.commit();
                tasarım.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences("color",MODE_PRIVATE);
    color=prefs.getString("colour","WHITE");

    if (color.equals("BLUE")){
        tasarım.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    else if(color.equals("RED")){
        tasarım.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }else{
        tasarım.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that alteast the items are being selected ... ?

Comment: what is the sharedPref returning for `prefs.getString("colour","WHITE");` if your position is 1?

Comment: you code of getString gets executed before you set the color, can you share the complete class code? Hence you will not get the color set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save my app background in SharedPreferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689300/how-to-save-my-app-background-in-sharedpreferences)

Comment: You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689300/how-to-save-my-app-background-in-sharedpreferences
This will help!

Comment: My teacher asked for my homework in this style, and if you find the lack of this code, you really help.

Comment: getString (color, WHITE) to start with white. Thanks Rahul.